# How can i make my project in asp.net log out automatically after minutes of idle (afk)..

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can i make my project in asp.net log out automatically after minutes of idle (afk)? I am using VB.Net

Comment: @bolek what kind of authentication you are using , and provide a bit more information .

Comment: give complete info as much as possible.

Comment: @SurajSingh for example.. a user logs in and after a few minutes he leaves his work station for certain amount of time... this means he is idle.. i want my project to automatically log out

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Form Authentication, You can use timeout functionality.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="10" slidingExpiration="true">
   </forms>
</authentication>
```

OR if not you can make use of session by assigning timeout attribute .
Check session in every page user can access after login.

```
<sessionState 
    mode="[Off|InProc|StateServer|SQLServer|Custom]"
    timeout="number of minutes"............

   ....../>
```

Comment: i tried your codes nothing happens.. when i put it in the source... sorry newbie here